# Hicks' Proof of Theorema Egregium

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

On page 28 of Hicks' Notes on Differential Geometry he proves:

(9) $D_X D_Y Z - D_Y D_X Z - D_{[X,Y]} Z = \langle L(Y),Z\rangle L(X) - \langle L(X),Z\rangle L(Y)$

where $D_X$ is the induced covariant derivative:
$D_X Y= \overline D  Y -\langle L(X),Y \rangle N $ and $\overline D_X Y$ is the usual directional derivative.

He then defines the left hand side as R(X,Y)Z and states that "(9) implies thatR(X,Y)Z depends only on $X_p,Y_p,Z_p$". How can I see this if the covariant derivative $D_X$ is defined using the normal vector N?

Comment: The vector $N$ depends on the cross product $X\times Y$ if they are tangent and linearly independent.

Comment: The point is that the shape operator $L$ is a tensor, so that $L(X)_p$ depends only on $X_p$. Note that $\langle L(X_p),Y_p\rangle = -\langle D_{X_p} N,Y_p\rangle$ depends only on $X_p$ and $Y_p$, not on other values of the vector fields $X,Y$. (The unit normal $N$ is already fixed by the embedding of the surface, nothing to do with these vector fields.)